# How can I simulate two SQL instances to test my stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a .NET-based web application with a SQL 2008 back end.  The SQL server contains about a dozen databases.

In our development environment, all of the databases live in the same SQL instance.  However, in production, there are actually two instances, with half of the databases on one instance and half on the other.  In production, we are not allowed to use linked servers (for security reasons).

Given the above constraints, it seems that it is easily possible to write SQL statements that would execute fine in the development environment but fail miserably in the production environment, because not all of the databases will be accessible with a single connection string.

I'm currently writing some reports that draw data from these databases and testing them in the development environment.  How can I make sure that what I'm writing will work in production?

I was thinking maybe setting up SQL server roles or users in a manner that restrict access to some of the databases, but am not sure this will work.

Comment: How about setting up two real SQL instances?

Comment: The company I work for (which is a behemoth) has a lot of red tape and budget constraints surrounding development environments.  Been trying to get that second instance and so far it is a no go.

Comment: You could run a second instance on the same server? Check the [Microsoft license guild pdf](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/7/0/270B6380-8B38-4268-8AD0-F480A139AB19/SQL2008R2_LicensingQuickReference-updated.pdf)

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to reliably detect all of them, but the dirty way I'd do it is use moq, and have the data access object that is mocked do a string.contains on the query to be executed to ensure that a query only contains references to schemas on one or the other database and not both